# Is to set SelectedRowStyle attribute a bad idea to change the background color of a selected row?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, gridview

What I want to achieve is to change the backtroung color of the selected row in a gridview.

I have the command field.

And I set the SelectedRowStyle="highlight" class.

But when I select the row, nothing changes :(

I know I can do some changes on Gridview event on the code behind. But I should be able to achive this just by a simple mark-up change instead of writing code to set CssStyle of each cell.

Pelase, can you see what am I doing wrong?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridViewResults_RowCommand"
                    SelectedRowStyle="highlight">
<Columns>
    <!-- Some bound fields here -->                 
    <asp:CommandField SelectText="Select >>" ShowSelectButton="true"/>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `SelectedRowStyle` to `SelectedRowStyle-CssClass` property

Comment: I had to play with selected index events etc. to achieve what I needed in the first place! Thanks Yuriy; it worked. But I have to say that SelectedRowStyle attribute is a bit missleading in my opinion.